# Google Calendar event etag decreases which leads to 'ifMatch' patching failure

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

My code modifies calendar events using Google Calendar API and it's subscribed to event changes (via calendars sync tokens, not push notifications, if it matters).
Changing event time from 'since X till Y' to 'all day' leads to a weird situation:

Let's say initial event etag is 0

1. Successfully patched an event to 'all day' if etag = 0, got new etag = 1
2. Got an update from the calendar - event is changed, new etag = 1 (that's right)
3. Successfully patched an event if etag = 1 (any change, e.g. set a new summary), got new etag = 2
4. Got an update from the calendar - event is changed, new etag = 3 (should be 2! also it has the same time of the last update as version returned after patching)
5. Trying to patch event again if etag = 3. Request fails because etag doesn't match, actual etag = 2
6. Trying to load new changes using calendar sync token - there are no changes

So it looks like a bug - false update was received and broke the synchronization. Or is it possible for etag to decrease? It only happens when a change from regular event to 'all day event' is involved.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet to reprodcue this behavior? Have also a look on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) if someone else encountered the same problem and filed a bug.

Comment: I've created a snippet that does the same but I can't reproduce the problem on it. In the main project it reproduces every time. The most strange part is that while my main code fails to patch an event wit etag=X I can patch it with the same etag=X from the snippet after that. Would appreciate any suggestion - why different clients (with the same configs) may get different etags?

Comment: I've found several issues related to event etags and 'ifMatch' patching but they have no answers. For example, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74055497 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117893507

Comment: You can "star" the issue or commenton it to increase visibility.

Comment: Frankly, it looks like most of these issues are ignored. For example this one is 10 years old, has a lot of comments and got no attention from Google side: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757162. So I don't think that creating an issue or voting for it might help.